# Summation of Near-Rising-Factorial

Tags: summation

Is there an easy way to find the closed form of

> $$\scriptsize\sum_{r=1}^n (r+\tfrac {2010}{10})(r+2011)(r+2012)(r+2013)(r+2014)(r+2015)(r+2016)(r+2017)(r+2018)$$

without first knowing the answer?

The answer is
$$\scriptsize{\frac 1{10}n}(n+2011)(n+2012)(n+2013)(n+2014)(n+2015)(n+2016)(n+2017)(n+2018)(n+2019)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $p(n)=(n+\tfrac {2010}{10})\prod_{i=2011}^{2018}(n+i)$ and $P(n)=\frac {1}{10}n\prod_{i=2011}^{2019}(n+i)$.

We would like to show that $P(n)=\sum_{r=1}^n p(n)$.

---

**Claim:** $P(n)-P(n-1)=p(n)$

**Proof:** Observe that

\begin{align*}
P(n)-P(n-1)&=\frac{1}{10}\left(n(n+2019)-(n-1)(n+2010)\right)\prod_{i=2011}^{2018} (n+1)\\
&=\frac{1}{10}(10n+2010)\prod_{i=2011}^{2018}(n+i)\\
&=p(n)
\end{align*}

---

It follows that

\begin{align*}
\sum_{r=1}^n p(r)&=\sum_{r=1}^n \left(P(r)-P(r-1)\right)\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^n P(r)-\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} P(r)\\
&=P(n)-P(0)\\
&=P(n)
\end{align*}

As desired $\blacksquare$

Comment: The intention was to work out the answer without first knowing the solution. This has been added to the question. Thanks for your solution anyway.  (+1)